# Rails 5.2 nested routes, and urls paths not working for delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have tried not to ask any questions regarding this and figure it out myself but now I am at a loss, thinking I might have to start over :(.  I generated a rails mysql project with `devise`, used scaffolding for categories, then products like so:

```
rails g scaffold category name:string description:text
rails g scaffold product name:string category:references
```

my routes.rb (for some reason create was not included with product/new)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'categories#index', as: :authenticated_root
      resources :categories do
        resources :products
      end
      post '/categories/:category_id/products/new' => 'products#new'
      put '/categories/:categoriy_id/products/:id' => 'products#create'
    end

    unauthenticated :user do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
      get 'sign-in' => 'devise/sessions#new'
      post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create'
      delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    end
  end
end
```

my products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to category_products_path
  end

  private

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

and my rake routes:

```
Prefix Verb       URI Pattern                                            Controller#Action
    new_user_session GET        /users/sign_in(.:format)                             devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST       /users/sign_in(.:format)                             devise/sessions#create
 destroy_user_session GET|DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                            devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST       /users/password(.:format)                            devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET        /users/password/new(.:format)                        devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET        /users/password/edit(.:format)                       devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH      /users/password(.:format)                            devise/passwords#update
                     PUT        /users/password(.:format)                            devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET        /users/cancel(.:format)                              devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST       /users(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET        /users/sign_up(.:format)                             devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET        /users/edit(.:format)                                devise/registrations#edit
                     PATCH      /users(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#update
                     PUT        /users(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE     /users(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#destroy
  authenticated_root GET        /                                                    categories#index
   category_products GET        /categories/:category_id/products(.:format)          products#index
                     POST       /categories/:category_id/products(.:format)          products#create
 new_category_product GET        /categories/:category_id/products/new(.:format)      products#new
 edit_category_product GET        /categories/:category_id/products/:id/edit(.:format) products#edit
    category_product GET        /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)      products#show
                     PATCH      /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)      products#update
                     PUT        /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)      products#update
                     DELETE     /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)      products#destroy
          categories GET        /categories(.:format)                                categories#index
                     POST       /categories(.:format)                                categories#create
        new_category GET        /categories/new(.:format)                            categories#new
       edit_category GET        /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                       categories#edit
            category GET        /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#show
                     PATCH      /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#update
                     PUT        /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#update
                     DELETE     /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#destroy
                     POST       /categories/:category_id/products/new(.:format)      products#new
                     PUT        /categories/:categoriy_id/products/:id(.:format)     products#create
  unauthenticated_root GET        /                                                    devise/sessions#new
             sign_in GET        /sign-in(.:format)                                   devise/sessions#new
               login POST       /login(.:format)                                     devise/sessions#create
              logout DELETE     /logout(.:format)                                    devise/sessions#destroy
```

Sorry for the length of this post I didn't want to leave anything out.  Really only needed routes.rb, anyway, as is the user is routed to 'show' product from categories, rather than 'delete', I am trying to 'delete' a product from categories.  And the product/index.html.erb has a 'delete' link as shown below, however that just shows a product,

```
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', action: "destroy", id: product.id, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Comment: Re: `put '/categories/:categoriy_id/products/:id' => 'products#create'`, why PUT (and not POST) for CREATE? Why (and how) are you passing `:id` in CREATE?

Comment: I thought i remember reading it should be PUT but sounds like POST is more appropriate, I was confusing a security flaw from earlier rails maybe?  Thank you!

Comment: _"I am trying to 'delete' a product from categories"_ - I assume your question is limited to products controller only. I will remove the extra code. Add it later if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that your routes.rb look more like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do

    authenticated :user do
      root 'categories#index', as: :authenticated_root
      resources :categories, shallow: true do
        resources :products
      end
    end

    unauthenticated :user do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
      get 'sign-in' => 'devise/sessions#new'
      post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create'
      delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    end

  end
end
```

This will give you routes like:

```
   category_products GET    /categories/:category_id/products(.:format)     products#index
                     POST   /categories/:category_id/products(.:format)     products#create
new_category_product GET    /categories/:category_id/products/new(.:format) products#new
        edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)                    products#edit
             product GET    /products/:id(.:format)                         products#show
                     PATCH  /products/:id(.:format)                         products#update
                     PUT    /products/:id(.:format)                         products#update
                     DELETE /products/:id(.:format)                         products#destroy
          categories GET    /categories(.:format)                           categories#index
                     POST   /categories(.:format)                           categories#create
        new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                       categories#new
       edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                  categories#edit
            category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                       categories#show
                     PATCH  /categories/:id(.:format)                       categories#update
                     PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                       categories#update
                     DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                       categories#destroy
```

Note that this gives you `new_category_product` and `category_products`, so you don't need:

```
  post '/categories/:category_id/products/new' => 'products#new'
  put '/categories/:categoriy_id/products/:id' => 'products#create'
```

(BTW, `:categoriy_id` is misspelled in the second line.)

Also note shallow nesting, which you can read more about in [the Guide, section 2.7 Nested Resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Then, you should be able to do:

```
<td>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</td>
```

Comment: Did that do the trick? If so, please feel free to upvote/accept for future searchers.